# How to write to binary file from 2 input array and interweaving the value, with Matlab or C

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, concatenation, video-processing

I am reading from two raw 8-bit video file of 256x256 frame size. One is the upper byte and one is the lower byte of a 16-bit raw video source.

I am struggling to use Matlab to either combine the two bytes into a single uint16 array to write to a file, or try to write the lower byte first and then the upper byte. Each time I use fwrite, I must write the full 256x256 frame of the upper byte, and then the full frame for the lower byte.

I have a loop like below that is working, but it is excruciatingly slow.

```
for j = 1:256
    for k = 1:256
        fwrite(RemergedFID, lowFrame(k,j), 'uint8');
        fwrite(RemergedFID, highFrame(k,j), 'uint8');
    end
end
```

Is there any better way and faster way to write out something like this?

Comment: Do you mean to say that each frame in the final output sequence has pixels of a 16-bit resolution where the upper half of the 16-bit word is an 8-bit pixel from one video, and the lower half of the 16-bit word is the 8-bit corresponding pixel from the other video?  Your wording is a bit ambiguous and unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of [`reshape`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and [`typecast`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) can do what you want in Matlab:

```
%% // optional, in case your frames are not always 256x256
nLine = size(highFrame,1) ;
nCol  = size(highFrame,2) ;

%% // if you like the "black magic" effect, in one line:
FullFrame = reshape( typecast( reshape( [lowFrame(:) highFrame(:)].' , [] , nLine*nCol*2 ) , 'uint16') , nLine , [] ) ;  %'//          

fwrite(RemergedFID, FullFrame, 'uint16'); %// then write the full matrix in one go
```

If you do not like long obscure lines, you can decompose it in:

```
%% // merge the 2x uint8 frames into a single uint16 frame (lower endian ordering)
FullFrame = [lowFrame(:) highFrame(:)] ;                    %// Make a double column with high and low bytes in lower endian ordering
FullFrame = reshape( FullFrame.' , [] , nLine*nCol*2 ) ;    %'// Reshape the transpose to get one single line vector
FullFrame = typecast( FullFrame , 'uint16') ;               %// cast every 2 uint8 value into a uint16 value (lower endian ordering)
FullFrame = reshape( FullFrame , nLine , [] ) ;             %// reshape that into an m*n matrix

fwrite(RemergedFID, FullFrame, 'uint16'); %// then write the full matrix in one go
```

---

Matlab, and most pc will use the lower endian byte ordering to order values of more than 8 bits. Unless you are writing a file for a system which you know will be specifically big endian ordering (some embedded processor are), I suggest you stick with lower endian, or better yet, let Matlab or your system handle it.

Comment: Thanks for this! I know typecast could be use for my case but I wasn't sure how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest creating a 16-bit frame where the upper half of each pixel in the 16-bit frame corresponds to the `lowFrame` and the other half in the 16-bit frame corresponds to the `highFrame`.  Your wording suggests the opposite, yet the way you are writing the results in MATLAB suggest what I have just said.  I'm going to go with the way you are writing it in your code, but you can change it according to what you want to do.

In any case, simply take the `lowFrame` and [`bitshift`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitshift.html) all of the bits to the left by 8, then **add** this result to `highFrame` to get the concatenated result.  By bitshifting one frame to the left by 8 bits, you would allow room for the other frame to occupy the lower half when you add.   You would then write this entire array at once to file.  Bear in mind that when you write arrays to file, arrays are written in **column**-major format.  This means that when you write arrays to file, the **columns** are stacked together in a single contiguous block and are written to file.  I don't know what application you're ultimately going to be using this for, but if you want a **row**-major format where the **rows** are stacked together in a single contiguous block, you'll need to transpose this output frame first before writing.  As such, do something like this:

```
lowFrame = uint16(lowFrame);
highFrame = uint16(highFrame);
outFrame = bitshift(lowFrame, 8) + highFrame;
fwrite(RemergedFID, outFrame, 'uint16');
%fwrite(RemergedFID, outFrame.', 'uint16'); %// Use this if you want row-major
```

What's important is the first two lines of code where we cast the frames, assuming that they are `uint8`, to `uint16`.  We must do this to allow for the bitshifting to work.  If we left this as `uint8`, the bitshifting would simply saturate the type, and so moving to the left by 8 bits would simply give a max of `255`.  The third line does the magic that allows you to concatenate the bits from both frames together as single 16-bit words, then you write the results to file.

In terms of performance, this will certainly be must faster than looping through your pixels because bitshifting requires almost no time at all as it is an atomic operation - the same goes for addition.